# Is there a xamarin component that will handle PIN entry?

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, xamarin-component

I see there is an iOS and iPad, P[IN Code Control](http://components.xamarin.com/view/pincodecontrol) xamarin component, that will give your a programmatic numeric keypad for PIN Entry.  Short of coding the entire thing using C# in Xamarin I would prefer to find a component.

I need a PIN  code control, xamarin component that is cross platform, which is the purpose of xamarin forms.  We will be using this on Android and iOS devices.

Has anyone see such a component on Xamarin's Component Store and I am using the wrong search terms, **PIN**, **Keypad**, **Numeric**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For future googlers: you might be interested in a small Xamarin.Forms library [XamarinFormsPinView](https://github.com/lassana/XamarinFormsPinView). I'm the author.

It's not very configurable, but should fill most common requirements.

[image] [image]

Comment: this is interesting. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to install nuget package but it gives dependency error in PCL project. Created an issue on github project. Please check

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I have not seen a component that does what you need.

This [Xamarin.Forms calculator sample](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/writing-cross-platform-mobile-apps-with-visual-studio-2015-and-xamarin-forms-2) might be a useful starting point for writing a custom one (since it already implements a numeric keyboard entry with display and backspace).

Obviously there's a lot of styling work required to get it looking like any of the native PIN entry screens - but it should save you writing from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you need attractive xamarin forms pin passcode form with high control, check out this repo. It is not a library and it does not use MVVM models. It is just .XAML page with code behind it.
https://github.com/Akezh/XamarinFormsPinPassword